# Refresh one child React component from form submit in sibling React component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component called Bills, which embeds two child components, AddBill and DisplayBills.

AddBill is a managed webform which submits the fields as json to an API endpoint (using fetch post).

DisplayBills gets Bill data as json from an API endpoint and displays this in an HTML table (using fetch).

When I click the submit button on the webform in AddBill, I would like to submit the data to the database via the API endpoint, and *then* I would like to do a refresh of DisplayBills to show this bill is now in the database.

I've tried several ways of wiring this up but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Simplest is for `Bills` to pass a callback like `onSubmit` into `AddBill` which `AddBill` calls, then `Bills` can set that info to state and pass it into `DisplayBills`

Comment: Ah, okay, in theory I understand that, but the mechanics of getting it right are a challenge. Let me see what some Googling can unearth. Thanks Dominic!

Comment: I'll make an example

Comment: That would be EXTREMELY helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your `handleAddBill` AND API call is successful, in your `state` save something like this `lastCall: Date.now()` and pass that piece of state to DisplayBills component as `props` `<DisplayBills lastCall={this.state.lastCall} />`. Now every time you call `handleAddBill` function, DisplayBills component's `props` will be updated with a unique value. In your DisplayBills component's `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` life-cycle method, check if `prevProps.lastCall !== this.props.lastCall`, if they are different, then make your new API call to fetch latest bills, if they are same, that means `handleAddBill` is not called successfully so you don't have to update your DisplayBills component.

Comment: Bingo!! Thank you @Samet M.!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a prop to inform the parent when a new bill is added, and add it to the bills state array which is passed into DisplayBills.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

function AddBill({ onAddBill }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [cost, setCost] = useState(0);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    onAddBill({ name, cost });
    setName('');
    setCost(0);
  }

  return (
    <form className="add-bill" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        placeholder="Bill name"
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        min="0"
        value={String(cost)}
        placeholder="Cost"
        onChange={e => setCost(Number(e.target.value))}
      />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function DisplayBills({ bills }) {
  if (!bills.length) {
    return <div>No bills yet!</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="bill-list">
      {bills.map(bill => (
        <div key={bill.name}>
          Bill {bill.name} cost ${bill.cost}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Bills() {
  const [bills, setBills] = useState([]);

  function handleAddBill(bill) {
    setBills([bill, ...bills]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="bills">
      <AddBill onAddBill={handleAddBill} />
      <DisplayBills bills={bills} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Bills />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-pine-o5c7g

Note that I have used the bill name as the unique key, so really I should be enforcing that it is unique, or else just creating a unique ID for each bill (arrays should have unique IDs for rendering in React).

As per comments if you're using class components your state will look more like this:

```
class Bills extends PureComponent {
  state = { bills: [] }

  handleBillAdd = bill => {
    this.setState({ bills: [bill, ...this.state.bills] });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what these lines are doing in 'Bills':
`const [bills, setBills] = useState([]);

  function handleAddBill(bill) {
    setBills([bill, ...bills]);
  }`

Comment: If you're using a class component it's the equivalent of state and `this.setState`. You have a bills array in state, and in `handleAddBill` you are adding a bill to it

Comment: If I'm using `class Bills extends Component` with a constructor, does `const [bills, setBills] = useState([]);` go inside the constructor?

Comment: No, although you could initialize state there (`this.state = {...}`) though I've done it in the shorter way - see updated answer for a snippet at the bottom

Comment: Hmmm. I can see that the child AddBill is triggering the parent handleAddBill function as I have a console.log() line in it which is being displayed in the console. But no refresh is being triggered in DisplayBill...

Comment: Ah, so one difference to the way your code works is that my DisplayBills component is 'autonomous' -- it does its own fetch from an API endpoint, it doesn't take in bill data from an array... would that make a difference?